# Click span element from div class

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I need to select testdt4 from the table. I am not able to get the whole list of the table items displayed as web elements. Like testdt4, there are many rows of the table which i need to find. Can I get the whole list in `List<WebElement>`? Please help.

```
<tr class="ng-scope" ng-class="::{warning: !$$cancelLastAction && (entity.$$inProgress || entity.$$hasError)}" ng-repeat="entity in locals.data">
<td class="selectRow">
<!-- ngRepeat: columnDef in locals.gridOptions.columnDefs -->
<td class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="columnDef in locals.gridOptions.columnDefs">
<ci-resource-grid-cell text-limit="textLimit" column="columnDef" data="entity">
<a class="ng-scope" ng-click="openLink(entity)" href="">
<div class="ciTruncate" truncate-limit="150" ci-truncate="columnDef.$$parse(entity)">

<span class="ng-scope">**testdt4**</span>

</div>
</a>
</ci-resource-grid-cell>
</td>
<!-- end ngRepeat: columnDef in locals.gridOptions.columnDefs -->
<td class="ng-scope" ng-repeat="columnDef in locals.gridOptions.columnDefs">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First - you need a established goal as to what you are trying to find. Are looking for all elements or Single element. If multiple elements.
   [https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/SearchContext.html#findElements-org.openqa.selenium.By-]
2. are you trying to find Cells or Rows or whole table? Cell tag - td/Row - tr/Table - table.
3. with find elements, xpath search with following will give you all cells:
   Xpath Expression::
   `"//td//span[contains(@class,"ng-scope") and contains(text(),"testdt4")]"`

Where I gave //tr above, replace with `table` or `tr` as needed [pt2]
Example:

Xpath Expression::
`"//tr//span[contains(@class,"ng-scope") and contains(text(),"testdt4")]"`

Xpath Expression::
`"//table//span[contains(@class,"ng-scope") and contains(text(),"testdt4")]"`

List someList = driver.findElement(By.xpath("Xpath Expression"))

Show me your code i will modify it:: Update You should be using TD for cells.

```
By identifierXPath = By.xpath("//tr//span[contains(@class,'ng-scope') and contains(text(),'testdt4')]"); 
List<WebElement> list_Cells = driver.findElements(identifierXPath);
System.out.println(list_Cells.size());
for (WebElement single_Cell : list_Cells){
    System.out.println("Cell Text ::-" + single_Cell.getText().trim());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Makjb lh for your response. Sorry that I was not able to set my question right. I am looking for all elements that are displayed in the tables. One such row value is testdt4. There are around 20 rows. I need to get all the 20 values. How do I show you my code?

Comment: Edit your question and copy paste what you coded/attempted in your question. Put it within ` ` marks [not ' ' ]. also can you upvote me ? on top of 0 , click up arrow and also Right mark.

Comment: I am trying to fetch all the values from one column of this table in to  `List<WebElement> findElements`. Value of one element from this list should be testdt4. Appreciate your quick help. Thanks. `By identifier = By.xpath("//table//span[contains(@class,'ng-scope')");
     List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(identifier);

     System.out.println("Print findElements---" + findElements.size());
     for (int i = 0; i <= findElements.size(); i++) {
      System.out.println("findElements******" + i + "*************"
        + findElements.get(i).getText());
     }`

Comment: What is the size of the elements you are getting. An additional thing might be this - the other tables might have different properties, if so you need to add code or xpath. Can you attach the HTML in a notepad

Comment: The table has pagination. On one page, its displaying 5 rows. I need to get all those elements from all the pages in one list (Around 18) so that I can iterate over the list and get at random any specified element.

Comment: Why do you want to do that randomization? If I am guessing right you need to get all the text values right, then do one thing - 1. `start a loop for 5 pages` and 2. `get elements`, 3. `start inner loop`, 4. `insert element text values into a array`, 5. `end inner loop` , 6. `click next page`, 7. `End Outer loop`. Now you have a single array of text values ..

Comment: Yes. Thats exactly what I want to do. But to get these elements into list the list, `By identifier = By.xpath("//table//span[contains(@class,'ng-scope')");
     List<WebElement> findElements = driver.findElements(identifier);` isnt working. What should be code to capture these elements?

Comment: Did you not use this instead:: `By identifierXPath = By.xpath("//tr//span[contains(@class,'ng-scope') and contains(text(),'testdt4')]")`;  Your table contains ng-scope will not work maam.